# Compiling bindings/pydrake/systems/primitives_py.cc failed: (Exit 1): cc failed: error executing comman

Tags: drake

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 to make drake source code, and I am in the last step of `make -j 4`.There was an error showed that:

```
ERROR: /home/yx/Downloads/Drake/drake/bindings/pydrake/systems/BUILD.bazel:86:21: Compiling bindings/pydrake/systems/primitives_py.cc failed: (Exit 1): cc failed: error executing command (from target //bindings/pydrake/systems:primitives.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so) /usr/bin/cc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections ... (remaining 247 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
cc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
Target //:install failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 392.578s, Critical Path: 374.60s
INFO: 30 processes: 17 internal, 13 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/build.make:112: drake_cxx_python-prefix/src/drake_cxx_python-stamp/drake_cxx_python-build] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:860: CMakeFiles/drake_cxx_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem? Thanks so much!!

I have run the `install_prereqs.sh` and my python is 3.8.10 cython version is 0.29.14

Comment: See https://drake.mit.edu/troubleshooting.html#build-oom

Comment: Thanks very much.I have solved it.